# Having trouble centering two form widgets horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout in which I want two ToggleButton widgets centered horizontally; not right next to each other, but as if each was centered in their own half of the view.
[image: So, I'm wanting them to look like this.]

[image: But instead I get this.]

Here is the code for my layout:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/pics"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/prefix"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp"/>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/suffix"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="4dp" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            orientation="horizontal" >
        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/lockPrefix"
                android:textOn="Locked"
                android:textOff="Unlocked"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            orientation="horizontal" >
        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/lockSuffix"
                android:textOn="Locked"
                android:textOff="Unlocked"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@id/pics"
        android:padding="8dp" >
    <Button android:id="@+id/mixButton"
            style="@style/DefaultButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:text="@string/main_mixButton"
            android:onClick="mixButtonClick" />
    <Button android:id="@+id/exitButton"
            style="@style/DefaultButton"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:text="@string/main_exitButton"
            android:onClick="exitButtonClick" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>`
```

(EDIT: make XML readable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place each button into a `LinearLayout`, set `layout_width` of these layouts to `fill_parent`, `layout_weight` to 1 and `gravity` to `center_horizontal`. Hope this helps!

Comment: I swear I tried that--must have put it on the `ToggleButton` instead of the `LinearLayout` (adding `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` did the trick).  I was also wondering if this was the most efficient way--seems to add a couple of extra view elements just to get it centered?  Seems to be the only option.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this , for toggle button, removing nested linear layouts. (I have replaced from 24th line I suppose)

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
>
      <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/lockPrefix"
               android:textOn="Locked"
               android:textOff="Unlocked"
               android:checked="false"
               android:layout_width="0dip"
               android:layout_weight="0.5"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <ToggleButton android:id="@+id/lockSuffix"
                android:textOn="Locked"
                android:textOff="Unlocked"
                android:checked="false"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

< /LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  This seems to makes each `ToggleButton` fill up half of the view width, though, which is not what I'm trying to do.